# Could not find the correct Provider<Example> above this Custom Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider, flutter-routes

In the code below I get no errors...until I debug and click on the bottom navigation bar icon to navigate to the route. That page then displays the red box of errors between my app bar and bottom navigation bar.

I'm getting the following error:

```
The following ProviderNotFoundException was thrown building TodaysReviewScreen(dirty):
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<Entries> above this TodaysReviewScreen Widget

This happens because you used a BuildContext that does not include the provider of your choice...
```

In main.dart, I've tried moving the MultiProvider up into runApp(), wrapping the MaterialApp with it, and in main_navigation.dart I tried wrapping the Scaffold with it. No luck.

Edit: Removed all the code since it was unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: It was a case sensitive import that was not flagged as a problem.